# URL Rewriting in my php website

Tags: php, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the URL of my php website? For example, let us consider that my website URL is this:

> www.abc.com/ab/firstpost-63

I want to change it to:

> www.abc.com/firstpost

with "ab" and "63" removed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: try this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: You can search for a [php router](https://www.google.com/#q=php+router) if you don't feel like writing one yourself